# Output of a command in a variable

Tags: shell-script, shell

I am generating the random string to change the password of users by shell scripting.
I am using the below command to generate the random string

```
 </dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'\''()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~' | head -c 13  ; echo
```

I am not able to put this on a variable.

Comment: ...specifically, scroll down to "How do I store a command in a variable?"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you've tried, but command substitution seems to work for me:

```bsh
x=$(</dev/urandom tr -dc 'A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'\''()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~' | head -c 13  ; echo)
echo "$x"
```

If this doesn't work for you then you might want to update the post with more information.

Comment: You should double-quote the variable reference (i.e. `echo "$x"`) -- the character list doesn't include spaces, but it does include shell wildcard characters, which have the potential to cause weird results if not quoted.